# RxJs 5 ascii marbles output for failing test

Tags: unit-testing, typescript, rxjs5

I am learning RxJS 5 (release candidate). I am using the ASCII [marble diagrams](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/manual/overview.html#marble-diagrams) in unit tests.

For a failing test, is there a built in function to show the `actual` ASCII marbles string instead of the deep equal failure result? It seems like if I have to understand and write an `expected` ASCII marble string that it would be useful for a failing test to show the actual ASCII marble string. It would assist in troubleshooting.

I am hoping that there is a built in function that is effectively the reverse of [`parseMarbles()`](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/spec/schedulers/TestScheduler-spec.ts). I have not found anything yet when searching through the documentation and source code.

Below is an example taken from [Writing marble tests - anatomy of a test](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/doc/writing-marble-tests.md#anatomy-of-a-test) that I modified to get a failing test. It gives the following output:

```
AssertionError: expected [ Array(5) ] to deeply equal [ Array(4) ]Error
```

I would rather see something like:

```
AssertionError: expected "'---(be)----c-f-----|'" 
                to equal "'---(be)----c-------|'"
```

http://jsbin.com/hipepew/edit?js,output

```
mocha.setup('bdd');
const expect = chai.expect; 

describe('RXJS 5 Marbles', () => {
  it("basic anatomy of a failing test", () => {

    const rxTestScheduler: TestScheduler = new Rx.TestScheduler(function (actual, expected) {
      expect(actual).to.deep.equal(expected);
    });
    const e1 = rxTestScheduler.createHotObservable<string>('----a--^--b-------c--|');
    const e2 = rxTestScheduler.createHotObservable<string>('---d-^--e---------f-----|');
    const expectedFail = '---(be)----c-------|';//missing f at frame 130
    rxTestScheduler.expectObservable(e1.merge(e2)).toBe(expectedFail);
    rxTestScheduler.flush();

  });
});

mocha.run();
```